# How to make this lightbox script run in jQuery.noconflict mode?

Tags: jquery, lightbox2

I assume [this script](https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/blob/master/js/lightbox.js) calls itself everytime with the `.call(this)` function which explains why I don't have to call it explicitly from the page HTML. Is this correct?

Can it be modified to run in `noconflict` mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially `.noConflict()` un-defines `$`. This means calls like

```
$.ajax(...);
$("a").some_func(...);
```

have to be changed to:

```
jQuery.ajax(...);
jQuery("a").some_func(...);
```

and so on.  Modify the script as such and it should work fine.

Comment: That's what I thought. However, it didn't work. Must be some other parts conflicting.g :(